# Limit incoming connections using iptables per IP

Tags: iptables

I need to limit access to some port per IP. Let's say 5 connections per minute - not more.

I've seen iptables **recent**, **connlimit** and **limit**, but all of them are not fitting exactly what I need.

Suppose you have a client trying to connect every second. In my scenario I need to allow 5 packets **each minute**.

**recent**: If some IP tries to connect every 1 second, --hitcount 5 will memorize this IP and keep it in the list until no packets comes within --second 60 time. So, it will limit the client permanently in my scenario.

**limit**: This one limits as I wish with --limit 5/min, but for all IPs - no way to specify this per IP.

**connlimit**: Limits number of simultaneous connections, not per some time.

In fact, I need a mixture of limit + recent. Who knows how to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to limit a specific application, say Apache or Postfix, or do you want something for a generic TCP application?

Comment: I need to limit number of connections to SSH server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to do it with recent:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW \
         -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 --name ssh --rsource \
         -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW \
         -m recent --set --name ssh --rsource
```

--update will restart the timer again on each receiving packet, but --rcheck will only check it. After 60 seconds the structure is deleted and a new timer is started again.

This is how I got it (I was not looking into sources - too lazy)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**hashlimit**](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbAW) match extension:

```
port=9999
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port        \
      -m conntrack --ctstate NEW              \
      -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name SuperUser \
                   --hashlimit-above 5/minute \
                   --hashlimit-mode srcip     \
      -j DROP
```

Debug version:

```
#!/bin/sh
dport=9999
limit=2/minute
burst=2

iptables -F
iptables -N SuperUser 2>/dev/null
iptables -N SuperUserLimited 2>/dev/null

# SuperUserLimited
iptables -A SuperUserLimited -j LOG                         \
                                 --log-level info           \
                                 --log-prefix 'SU:dropped '
iptables -A SuperUserLimited -j DROP

# SuperUser
iptables -A SuperUser -j LOG                         \
                          --log-level info           \
                          --log-prefix 'SU:new '
iptables -A SuperUser -m hashlimit                   \
                          --hashlimit-name SuperUser \
                          --hashlimit-above $limit   \
                          --hashlimit-burst $burst   \
                          --hashlimit-mode srcip     \
                      -j SuperUserLimited
iptables -A SuperUser -j LOG                         \
                          --log-level info           \
                          --log-prefix 'SU:accepted '

# main
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $dport \
                  -m state --state NEW  \
                  -j SuperUser
```

Comment: Hm, never seen hashlimit while googling. But I don't understand how it works:

**iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name SSH --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-above 5/min -j REJECT**

this call does not trap any command, while

**iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name SSH --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit 5/min -j REJECT**
traps all new connections...

Comment: I don't see `--hashlimit` option in the documentation, so the second command should have raised an error.

Comment: It seems I've an old iptables, where hashlimit seems to be same as hashlimit-upto. May be it does not work being to old.

Comment: I have iptables-1.4.19.1-1.fc20.x86_64.

Comment: @PoltoS, what iptables version do you have? What distribution?

Comment: iptables v1.4.12

finally was fixed with 

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 --name ssh --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Comment: Can you please provide the full solution with some details? I know, we need to have --set rule for adding source IP into the list. I want to know how it can be done.

Comment: I need a similar approach if a burst comes from an IP, I need to block that IP for few minutes. I am experimenting with recent option but, I could not block that IP address for few minutes. It is been added into the list which won't be removed at all.

Comment: Let's assume a scenario where I need to block an IP for 5minutes if IP sends 10connection/second. I could not DROP the connection from an IP for 5mins. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of connections is to use `connlimit` match.
an example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

that will reject connections above 5 from one source IP.
If you want to protect from a DDoS attack use `hashlimit`, you can limit them per IP, per combination IP + port, etc.
So an example for a web server will be something like this

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m hashlimit --hashlimit 45/sec --hashlimit-burst 60 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name DDOS --hashlimit-htable-size 32768 --hashlimit-htable-max 32768 --hashlimit-htable-gcinterval 1000 --hashlimit-htable-expire 100000 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @PoltoS, How is it ?

Comment: This is not what I want. This limits simultaneous connections, while I need to limit total number of connections established (and may be ended) during 1 minute.